# update using inner join only affecting 1 row?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to update table named directory , from a table named files , when i use the sql below it is only updating the first row

```
UPDATE dbo.directory
SET    navigateurl = (SELECT files.filename
                      FROM   dbo.files
                             INNER JOIN directory
                               ON dbo.directory.id = files.id
                      WHERE  ( files.id = directory.id ));
```

in tables files i have :

```
id | filename    
1  | index.html    
1  | index2.html    
1  | index3.html    
2  | aio.html    
2  | aaa.html
```

and so on

and in table directory i have :

```
id | parent_id | name | navigateurl
```

what i want to do is to be able to update directory table so that the field parent_id in table directory will be updated to the field id of files and the field navigateurl will be updated to filename  where directory.id = files.id , my query above only affects the

first row

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Give desired results for your example data.

Comment: show the data present in `directory` table.

Answer (score 0):

put the Where cluase outside the second select .i mean put it for the first select like this :

```
UPDATE dbo.directory
SET    navigateurl = (SELECT files.filename
                      FROM   dbo.files
                             INNER JOIN directory
                               ON dbo.directory.id = files.id )
WHERE  ( files.id = directory.id ) ;
```